# AWS Lambda pull image from public ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I've been trying to understand if it's possible to run AWS Lambda with a public docker image. I get that I can only use ECR, but can I use public ECR? Do I have to pull an image from a public ECR and push it into my private ECR? Does anybody know how can I specify public image correctly?

I have tried to use image from public ECR. f.e.

```
public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest
```

And I get:

```
Source image public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest is not valid. Provide a valid source image.
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for public vs private ECR, but do you realize that Lambda requires docker images to implement the Lambda runtime interface? Lambda can't run any docker image, the image has to be specifically configured to handle AWS Lambda requests https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Open-source runtime interface clients (RIC), You will need to add a Runtime interface client to the base image to make it compatible with Lambda.
the following links are for your information.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html#runtimes-api-client

Comment: I have a Docker file based on AWS's image: ```FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12``` and I still got the same error when fetching from public ECR repository: ```Resource handler returned message: "Source image public.ecr.aws/n1m0d6w1/telegram-bot-lab4:latest is not valid. Provide a valid source image.```